# Understanding the limit of the ratio $\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))}$ as r goes to 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We work in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $B(x,r)=\{y: |x-y|<r\}$. Let $\mu$ be any Borel Measure induced by a right continous increasing function and $m$ the Lebesgue Measure. What can we say about $lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))}$ for $\mu$ almost every x? Is it a positive number for $\mu$ almost every x? Is it the case that as r gets very small, $u(B(x,r))$ is at best of order r? What about the limit? Is it the case that the limit is non zero for $\mu$ almost every x? Thanks guys.

Comment: If $\mu\ll m$ this is pretty much covered by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.  See Bogachev's *Measure Theory*, p.367, 368, for $m$-almost everywhere results.   But that's not the $\mu$-almost everywhere result you want.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu  = \delta_0$, then clearly $\mu(B (0, r)) =1$ independently of $r $.  Thus, there's no hope of getting some kind of control over this with respect to $r $.

However, if $\mu $ and $m $ are mutually singular and $\mu $ is a Radon measure on $\mathbb {R}^{d}$, then 
$$\limsup_{r \to 0} \frac {\mu (B (x, r))} { m (B (x, r))} = \infty $$
for $\mu $-a.e. $x $.  The same limit is zero for $m $-a.e. $x $.

On the other hand, if $\mu $ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$, then 
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac {\mu (B (x, r))} { m (B (x, r))} = \frac {d \mu}{d m}(x) $$
for $m $-a.e. $x $.

In general, $\mu $ can be decomposed into a sum of absolutely continuous and singular measures, and then the limit will be determined by which measure "sees" $x $.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, do you mean limit as r goes to 0 instead of goes to infinity?

Comment: How do you get the claim in the case of a singular measure? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Also is it the case that for $\mu$ almost every x, $d\mu/dm$ is positive? (if $\mu$ is the measure induced by increasing right continuous function?

Comment: No, it's not true that $\frac{d \mu}{d m}$ is positive $\mu$-a.e.  Think about what would happen if $d \mu = \chi_{[0,1]} dx + d \delta_{2}$.  Then $\frac{d \mu}{d m} = \chi_{[0,1]}$, which vanishes in any neighborhood of $2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX, I learned this in the first volume of the harmonic analysis series by Muscalu and Schlag.  If you want, ask a new question and I will explain how to prove this.

Comment: fourierwho, sorry I meant if the measure has no atoms, is it true that the derivative is positive u a.e. ?

Comment: No, there's no reason why $\frac{d \mu}{dm}$ should be positive $\mu$-a.e.  In fact, $\frac{d \mu}{dm}$ is positive $\mu$-a.e. if and only if $\mu \ll m$.  This is a fact about the Lebesgue decomposition and has nothing to do with Lebesgue measure.